# Fast lighting with multiple lights

Tags: xna, shaders, performance, hlsl, lighting

How can I implement fast lighting with multiple lights?

I don't want to restrain the player, he can place an unlimited number and possibly overlapping (point) lights into the level.

The problem is that shaders which contain dynamic loops which would be necessary to calculate the lighting tend to be very slow.

I had the idea that if it could be possible at compiletime to compile a shader n times where n is the number of lights. If the number n is known at compiletime, the loops can be unrolled automatically. Is this possible to generate n versions of the same shader with just a different number of lights?

At runtime I could then decide which shader to use for which part of the level.

Comment: If the lights are added dynamically by the player, how can a "compiletime" shader be the correct answer?

Comment: As I wrote, the compiler could generate shaders for 1,2,3,..lights and at runtime I could decide which one to use for which portion of the level

Comment: compile time shaders need to know where the lights are going to be placed, any dynamicness of the lights will ruin them

Comment: only the number of lights should be dynamic. the positions will be provided as parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you  have your answer. You know the maximum number of lights and the range of possible positions.

Comment: which answer? which maximum number of lights and which possible positions? I want no hard maximum and the user can place light anywhere..

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you are looking for is called Deferred Rendering.
It is a rendering technique that scales extremely well with a lot of lights, so well that it can used for dynamic indirect illumination. That means 1000s of lights on the screen.

It is basically a technique in which you first render all your geometry data(position, normal, depth) into an intermediate pixel buffer(called the G-Buffer). 
Then in a second pass you render a light shape along with its parameters. The shader of this second pass takes the information from the G-Buffer, applies light calculation, then blends it into the final image.

You can find implementation details [here](http://homepage.lnu.se/staff/tblma/Deferred%20Rendering%20in%20XNA%204.pdf)